# Unity IOS PostProcessBuild

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build

In Unity, because of the packages i use in project i need to run pod commands after build. Doing it every time takes so much time. I want to run pod commands after build automatically. I use the code below to run pod commands but it says Run command not found. I tried $ instead of run but it didn't work. How can i run these commands ?

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_IOS
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

public class XcodePostProcess
{
    [PostProcessBuild]
    static void OnPostProcessGenPodfile(BuildTarget buildTarget, string pathToBuiltProject)
    {
        if (buildTarget != BuildTarget.iOS)
            return;

        // update the Xcode project file
        var projPath = Path.Combine(pathToBuiltProject, "Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj");
        var project = new UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode.PBXProject();
        project.ReadFromFile(projPath);

        // Get the Podfile and copy it into the Xcode project folder
        var target = project.GetUnityFrameworkTargetGuid();
        File.Copy("Assets/Editor/MyPodfile", Path.Combine(pathToBuiltProject, "Podfile"), true);

        project.AddBuildProperty(target, "CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES", "YES");
        File.WriteAllText(projPath, project.WriteToString());


        List<Process> processes = new List<Process>()
        {
            new Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                   WorkingDirectory = pathToBuiltProject,
                   FileName = "/usr/local/bin/pod",
                   Arguments = "Run rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData",
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                },
            },
             new Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                   WorkingDirectory = pathToBuiltProject,
                   FileName = "/usr/local/bin/pod",
                   Arguments = "Run pod deintegrate",
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                },
            }, new Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                   WorkingDirectory = pathToBuiltProject,
                   FileName = "/usr/local/bin/pod",
                   Arguments = "Run pod cache clean --all",
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                },
            }, new Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                   WorkingDirectory = pathToBuiltProject,
                   FileName = "/usr/local/bin/pod",
                   Arguments = "Run pod repo update",
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                },
            }, new Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                   WorkingDirectory = pathToBuiltProject,
                   FileName = "/usr/local/bin/pod",
                   Arguments = "Run pod install",
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                },
            }, new Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                   WorkingDirectory = pathToBuiltProject,
                   FileName = "/usr/local/bin/pod",
                   Arguments = "Run pod update",
                   UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                },
            }
        };

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < processes.Count; i++)
            {
                processes[i].Start();
                while (!processes[i].StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = processes[i].StandardOutput.ReadLine();

                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(line);
                }
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"{processes[i].StartInfo.Arguments} completed");
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing 'Run pod' from your arguments. You are already specifying that you wish to use the pod command via the Filename argument, so try something like this in your StartInfo arguments:

```
FileName = "/usr/local/bin/pod",
Arguments = "update"
```

Comment: "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" to run this code i need to change file name to "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" and arguments to "rm -rf" is it true ?

Comment: If you use:

    FileName = "/bin/rm"
    Arguments = "-rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"

Then this should have the effect of calling the 'rm' command with the arguments '-rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData', which will recursively delete the DerivedData directory.

Generally speaking you should only use rm -rf if you are *absolutely* sure you want to delete it and everything below it.